# Function 'TD_LEFT' called with an invalid number or type of parameters - Teradata

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Below is the data in the excel file and I am trying to get the below mentioned output image as output in excel using Python. Thank you.

### Data frame - Input

| Class | Student |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | A |
| 10 | B |
| 10 | C |
| 9 | D |
| 9 | E |

### Data frame - Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Where's your code that gives the error? Is this teradata or excel or dataframe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging Specific Cells in an Excel Sheet with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67732103/merging-specific-cells-in-an-excel-sheet-with-python)