# Is there any to way to merge cells when there any colspan or rowspan in table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I just currently develop an api that take user table as in html and try to turn it into excel by using pandas. but the problem I'm facing rn is that i want to merge any cells base "td" that has colspan or rowspan but pandas doesn't seem to know it. Instead it copy the current "td" value to another cell instead of merging it. Is there any way to achieve this?

**this is a code that I wrote.**

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import lxml

df = pd.read_html("""
    <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Age</th>

     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td colspan=2>Test</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Test</td>
       <td>20</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
""")[0]

df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

**and this a result**

[image]

**expected result**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please insert your code as text, instead of an image?

Comment: @Nelewout i just changed from image to code. Do you know any way to solve  this or get arround it?

Comment: Unfortunately not!

Comment: The only way pandas can merge cell by default is when they are part of the index/columns.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, the way to proceed is using multi-index like in the following scripts.

**Merge using your dataframe**

- Your dataframe :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("""
    <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Age</th>

     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td colspan=2>Test</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Test</td>
       <td>20</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
""")[0]

# >>> df
#    Name   Age
# 0  Test  Test
# 1  Test    20
```

- Suggested script :

```py
# Create MultiIndex DataFrame
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(list(df.iloc[0]), df.columns), names=["first", "second"])
df = df.drop(axis=0, index=0).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df.to_excel('text.xlsx', merge_cells=True)
```

- Dataframe visualization in Python Interpreter :

```
first   Test    
second  Name Age
0       Test  20
```

- Dataframe visualization in XL :

[image]

**Other example**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"],
          ["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"]]
 
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
# [('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two'), ('baz', 'one'), ('baz', 'two'), 
# ('foo', 'one'), ('foo', 'two'), ('qux', 'one'), ('qux', 'two')]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["first", "second"])

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index)
# first  second
# bar    one       0.469112
#        two      -0.282863
# baz    one      -1.509059
#        two      -1.135632
# foo    one       1.212112
#        two      -0.173215
# qux    one       0.119209
#        two      -1.044236
# dtype: float64

s.to_excel('text.xlsx', merge_cells=True)
```

**Output in XL**

[image]

**Notes**

Note that you need to activate the property `merge_cells` to merge multi-indexes. For more see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Or you could choose to merge after sending dataframe to excel. For more see there : [Merging Specific Cells in an Excel Sheet with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67732103/merging-specific-cells-in-an-excel-sheet-with-python)